# Relative Dates in query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I have this query for elasticsearch SQL. It seems to be standard SQL. Here is the code:

```
SELECT * FROM index WHERE date > '00:00 2019-07-31'
```

Instead of that, I want it to be relative, so the query can be run every day and show the last 30 days. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to use **current_date** and **interval** to accomplish what you want.

```
SELECT * FROM index WHERE date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY
```

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/sql-functions-datetime.html

Comment: Thank you. This isn't probably your fault, but it gives me this error. Any idea why? [essql] > Unexpected error from Elasticsearch: [parse_exception] failed to parse date field [2019-07-02T00:00Z] with format [HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd]: [Text '2019-07-02T00:00Z' could not be parsed at index 2]

Comment: I think it's just saying that the text in your field doesn't adhere to the expected date format. The format says HH:mm yyyy-MM-dd but you have yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ in your input. Perhaps this helps: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html